# show by induction if there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb N $such that $n\geq n_0 , n! \gt 2n^3$

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I tried and I got there doesn't exist such a $n_0$

However, I dun think I have a formal proof for this.

My approach is, First assume there is such a $n_o$ exist
and start my calculation with induction

$(n+1)!\\
  =(n+1)n!\\
   \gt(n+1)2n^3 (Induction Premise)\\
= 2n^4 + 2n^3\\
\gt 2n^3+6n^2+6n+1 , n \geq 3 \\
= 2(n+1)^3
$

So I get $n_0$ = 3, But when I subsitute back to the original equation, it doesn't work,
so, what can i conclude?
It doesn't exist such a $n_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a base case.  You're right that $n_0=3$ doesn't work, but that does not mean that there is no $n_0$ that works.  What you've shown is that for your inductive step to work, you will need $n$ to be at least $3$, but there is still the requirement that you get the inequality to hold once in the first place.

So, one way to proceed is to find an $n_0>3$ for which the inequality holds, then prove by induction that the inequality holds for all $n\geq n_0$.

In fact, you can make your induction step a little easier by taking $n_0$ (very) slightly larger than necessary.  If $n\geq 7$, then $2(n+1)^3<2(2n)^3=8(2n^3)\leq(n+1)2n^3$.

Comment: So, how can I find the base case? 7? Just guess? or 6?

Comment: @TimothyLeung: Using a calculator helps for more complicated examples, but basically, yes, for simple cases like this a little guess and check does the trick for establishing a base case.  You seem to have observed that $6$ is the smallest that works.  Keep in mind that for what you are trying to show, any larger $n_0$ will still work.  For example, it is easy and quick to show that $10!>2(10)^3=2000$.

Comment: @TimothyLeung:  as you posted the problem, there was no requirement to find the minimum $n_0$, but you needed to find one.  You have a fine inductive proof, but need a base case.  I find it amusing that working offline, I felt sure that $n_0=10$ (same as Jonas Meyer chose) would work.  If I were doing the problem, my pride would insist that I find the smallest $n_0$, but that was not required.